# Handling complex types xml-reader in c#

Tags: c#, xml

for example i have following XML:
I want to read the Sender object with an XML-Reader:

```
<gesmes:Sender>
<gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
</gesmes:Sender>
```

I wrote following parser:

```
 using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new FileStream(Console.ReadLine(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read)))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    switch (reader.LocalName)
                    {
                        case "Sender":
                            do
                            {
                                reader.Read();
                            } while (reader.LocalName != "name");
                            Console.WriteLine("Sended from:" + reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

That isn't quite elegant, is there another method with the Xml-reader, or is this the only way?

R3turnz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best method.  Always work without errors.  Uses XmlReader and xml Linq.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new FileStream(Console.ReadLine(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read)))
            {
                while (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    if (reader.Name != "name")
                    {
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("name");
                    }
                    if(!reader.EOF)
                    {
                        XElement name = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers. But i tried to ask for another method WITH THE XML-READER. I will have a look at the other

Answer (score 0):

If there is a single element `name`, we can use the simplest code:

```
string path = "..."; // path to file
string ns = "..."; // specify correct namespace

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("name", ns);
    string name = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

If there are many nodes `Sender` and `name`, and must properly consider the level of nesting, we have to complicate the code:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
{
    while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Sender", ns))
    {
        using (var innerReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
        {
            if (innerReader.ReadToFollowing("name", ns))
            {
                string name = innerReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                Console.WriteLine(name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my view, it's more elegant and correct.

Answer (score 0):

you know how to try it, but write the file you use in the "NAME" section is worth a try, man.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

    using (XmlReader xmlreader = XmlTextReader.Create(xmlStream))
                 {
                     while (xmlreader.Read())
                          {
                              if (xmlreader.IsStartElement())
                                  {
                                      switch (xmlreader.Name) // folder variable
                                    {
                                        case "NAME": // xml in label variable
                                            if (xmlreader.Read())
                                            {
                                                Names_List.Add(xmlreader.Value.Trim());
                                                NumLabels += 1; //order of the column in the xml file
                                            }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```